# How to pull data in an ArrayList until RAM doesn't get exhausted

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a java function. The return-type of this function is an `ArrayList<String>`.
There might be a situation when the returned `ArrayList` has near about 1 million elements, and it crosses the available RAM, and throws Exception.
How do I handle this situation. I don't wish the code to break due to exceptions.
Is there a way where I can specify to pull a particular number of elements, then discard them and process the next few number of elements...something like a buffer size ?
Below is the code what I am doing:

```
ArrayList<String> users = getUsers(); 
...
...
...

private ArrayList<String> getUsers() throws Exception{
    //connect to MongoDB
    ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
    userList = //get the list of users.
    return userList;
}
```

I was thinking that won't the line `ArrayList<String> users = getUsers();` throw an Exception when the returned list cross the available memory limit if the returned list is too huge ?
How do I handle this situation ?

Comment: You could give a sufficient large capacity to the ArrayList constructor, so no copies of old array to larger new array happens. The approach probably should be different, mapped memory using bytes, maybe using a ByteArrayOutputStream wrapped in a GZippedOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard solutions that come to mind:

1) pagination: pass two numbers to the method specifying the page number and page size. In the calling code, process the results before calling the method again with the next page number:

```
private void processUsers() {
    int pageSize = 42;
    // the first page is page 1
    int page = 1;    
    List<String> users = getUsers(page, pageSize); 
    while(!users.isEmpty()) {        
        processPage(users);
        users = getPage(++page, pageSize); 
    }
}

private List<String> getPage(int page, int pageSize) {               
    int maxIndex = countTotalResults() - 1;
    int startIndex = Math.MIN((page - 1) * pageSize, maxIndex);
    int endIndex = Math.MIN(startIndex + pageSize, maxIndex);
    return listUsers(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

2) streaming: instead of returning a List, return a Stream. Process the stream using Java 8 stream API. It's even possible to let the JVM process streams in parallel, for example:

```
double average = roster
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
    .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

Comment: I will try these and let you know the results :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try paginate the data with:

```
db.userdetails.find().skip(1000).limit(100);
```

In the scenario above you will skip the first 10 pages and get page 11.

Comment: I will try this and let you know what i am getting :)